# Java SWT - Key pressed display filter

Tags: java, swt, listener

In my app I added a filter to the display that handles a KeyDown event.
It works just fine when the app is running on windows, but now that I'm trying to run it on Linux it doesn't detect the keypress event.

Any ideas what can be the problem?

The code is a bit messy so I'm adding only the outline for now.

```
answerListener = new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                             ...
                    };

Display.getDefault().addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, answerListener);
```

The app Is a trivia game, when I press a key in the game screen, I should get 4 sec to choose an answer. So the answers button is enabled only if a key is pressed before.
There are 3 main  SWT composites on the screen. A group with the answers buttons, A list with text strings, and another group at the left of the screen.

[image]

When I press on the list of strings with the mouse and then I press a key, a small text box (you can see at the picture) with my pressed key char pops up, but the answers are still disabled.

The text box appears on the screen for 4 sec and then disappears.
When I click before on any other group, the small window don’t pop up, but the answer group are again disabled.

On Windows none of those symptoms occur. The game works as it should work.

Comment: Does the filter not fire at all? Try adding a sysout as the first line in the filter.

Comment: no it doesn’t fire at all. I added sysout in the first line and its not printing it.

Comment: Just tested it here on Linux Mint and it works absolutely fine. Which distribution do you use? Do you add another filter somewhere?

Comment: ubuntu 13.10 64 bit. I want to use this filter only in a specific screen in my app, so every time I enter this screen I add the filter, and every time I exit the screen I remove it with the following code

Comment: if (answerListener != null) {
 Display.getDefault().removeFilter(SWT.KeyDown,      answerListener);
  }

Comment: one more thing that is worth to mention is that the answerListener is static. it is static because I want to make sure that every time I add a new filter (as I explained before) I over write answerListener. When he was not static, I used to get a widget dispose errors

Comment: Im very sorry, I had a mistake and it is actually gets into the listener. I will now edit the question that the problem will be more clear